# Is there a way to restart a service on a remote machine from a batch script?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, services

I'm looking for a way to restart Windows services

- from batch scripts (preferrably CMD)
- on a remote machine
- using a different account than the one the script is running as

Looking at the parts that I already have in place, the missing bits are:

- runas does not provide a way to specify the password, so I can't call the remote machine with the appropriate account
- There seems to be no command line equivalent of the restart button in services.msc, so I would have to implement this myself by polling `sc query`

Are there any standard solutions to these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to restart services by using `sc stop` and `sc start` or `net stop` `net start`, if using `net`, then you have to use real name of service (as in `sc query`).

For remote connection to Windows and run batch commands under another use, you can use [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) from systeminternals.

Comment: Thanks for the psexec hint, that was the missing bit. I can now run the start/stop command directly on the remote machine, e.g. psexec \\servername -u username -p password sc stop ServiceName